# The Yocto bbclass folders structure misunderstanding

Tags: yocto-recipe

I have a relatively simple question but probably not for me.

I created a bbclass named spi-nand-ubi.bbclass. In this file, I have a few records like

```
    dd if=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${KERNEL_DEVICETREE} of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=512 conv=notrunc
    dd if=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE} of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=640 conv=notrunc
```

and above records are fine, but the following record don't

```
    dd if=${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}${IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX}.ubi of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=5504 conv=notrunc
```

I get always an error like

```
    dd: failed to open '/home/mw/yocto/tmp/work/indus-poky-linux-gnueabi/console-image/1.0-r0/deploy-console-image-image-complete/console-image-indus-20230120084720.rootfs.ubi': No such file or directory
```

When I type manually to the

```
    cd /home/mw/yocto/tmp/work/indus-poky-linux-gnueabi/console-image/1.0-r0/deploy-console-image-image-complete
```

the file with provided name exists.

What I missed, misunderstood. Please give me a hint on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like something is wrong in your path or file name.
Can you please post the output of `ls` command of your directory `/home/mw/yocto/tmp/work/indus-poky-linux-gnueabi/console-image/1.0-r0/deploy-console-image-image-complete` ?

Answer (score 1):

directory content of

> /home/mw/yocto/tmp/work/indus-poky-linux-gnueabi/console-image/1.0-r0/deploy-console-image-image-complete

```
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.ext4
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.jffs2
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.manifest
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.sunxi-spinand
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.tar
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.tar.gz
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.tar.xz
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.ubi
console-image-indus-20230120082905.rootfs.ubifs
console-image-indus-20230120082905.testdata.json
console-image-indus-20230120084720.rootfs.sunxi-spinand
console-image-indus-20230120084720.rootfs.tar
console-image-indus-20230120084720.rootfs.tar.gz
console-image-indus-20230120084720.rootfs.tar.xz
console-image-indus.ext4
console-image-indus.jffs2
console-image-indus.manifest
console-image-indus.testdata.json
console-image-indus.ubi
console-image-indus.ubifs
ubinize-console-image-indus-20230120082905.cfg
```

the content of my spi-nand-ubi.bbclass

```
inherit image_types
#
# Create an image that can by written into a SPI NAND (128 MBytes) flash technology using dd application.
# Written for Indus board to simplify programming process and to write only one combined image file.
#
# The image layout(layout is valid for 128MBytes Flashes) used is:
#
#    OFFSET                    PARTITION SIZE                PARTITION
#    0                      -> 458752(0x80000)             - SPL U-Boot with NAND offset
#    512*1024               -> 65536(0x20000)              - The dtb file
#    640*1024               -> 4980736(0x4C0000)           - Kernel
#    5504*1024              -> 122494976(0x7AA0000)        - Ubifs rootfs (*.ubi for NAND)
#
#    SUM of all partition should give all flash memory size, 
#    SUM = 0x70000+0x10000+0x4C0000+0x7AA0000= 0x7A12000(128000000)
#
#    Before change partition offsets here, do it first for U-Boot DTS, defconifg and Kernel DTS

# This image depends on the rootfs image
RDEPENDS_mtd-utils-tests += "bash"
SPINAND_ROOTFS_TYPE ?= "ubifs"
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_sunxi-spinand= "${SPINAND_ROOTFS_TYPE}"

do_image_sunxi_spinand[depends] += " \
            mtools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
            dosfstools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
            virtual/kernel:do_deploy \
            virtual/bootloader:do_deploy \
            "

# The NAND SPI Flash image name
SPINAND = "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}.rootfs.sunxi-spinand "

IMAGE_CMD:sunxi-spinand () {
    ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/mknanduboot.sh ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${SPL_BINARY} ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${NAND_SPL_BINARY}
    dd if=/dev/zero of=${SPINAND} bs=1M count=16
    dd if=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${NAND_SPL_BINARY} of=${SPINAND} bs=1k conv=notrunc
    dd if=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${KERNEL_DEVICETREE} of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=512 conv=notrunc
    dd if=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${KERNEL_IMAGETYPE} of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=640 conv=notrunc
    mkfs.ubifs -F -r ${WORKDIR}/rootfs -m 2048 -e 126976 -c 2048 -o ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/rootfs.ubifs
    #ubinize -vv -o ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/rootfs.ubi -m 2048 -p 131072 -s 2048 ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/config.ini
    #ubinize -vv -o ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/rootfs.ubi -m 2048 -p 131072 -s 2048 ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/ubinize${vname}-${IMAGE_NAME}.cfg
    dd if=${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}${IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX}.ubi of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=5504 conv=notrunc
    #dd if=${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/rootfs.ubi of=${SPINAND} bs=1k seek=5504 conv=notrunc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a few experiments and I think I found a reason. The problem is that ubi and ubifs are generated later than the receipt which uses my bbclass. This is the reason why it doesn't see demanded files. The question is what should I add to wait on ubi and ubifs to be finalized?